# Django no fue reconocido después de instalarlo

Tags: python-3.x, django, pip

Intento instalar Django. Pero despues instalaro parece no ser reconocido:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\Django\password_generator>pip3 install django
Requirement already satisfied: django in c:\python36\lib\site-packages (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in c:\python36\lib\site-packages (from django) (0.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref~=3.2.10 in c:\python36\lib\site-packages (from django) (3.2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\python36\lib\site-packages (from django) (2018.7)

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\Django\password_generator>django -V
'django' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\Django\password_generator>django -v
'django' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Cuando intento ejecutar algunos comandos no obtengo nada:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\Django\password_generator>python3 manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 1):

el problema es que al instalar django almenos en windows, este no se crea la variable de entorno o PATH con dicho nombre, en su lugar crea la variable django-admin. Prueba poner lo siguiente en tu cmd

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\Django\password_generator>django-admin --version
```

la otra via es llamar a python en tu cmd e importar django, una vez importado puedes ver la versión

```
C:\Users\Vicente>python
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(2, 2, 6, 'final', 0)
>>>
```